# statistically dispositive

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Court also, however, reaffirmed that
>   quotas were illegitimate and found that the undergraduate program, which mechanically awarded
>   minorities a fixed twenty points, was therefore impermissible because it was too similar to a quota.
>   However, it upheld the law school’s program, which purportedly treated race as merely a vague
>   “plus” and aimed for a “critical mass” of minorities rather than a fixed quota. But Justice O’Connor’s
>   majority opinion barely responded to the criticisms of the dissent that the so-called plus ended up
>   being **statistically dispositive** and that the critical mass was in fact, historically, a disguised quota,
>   largely taking the government’s word that the process was individualized.

I referenced http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispositive?q=dispositive but I still don't apprehend the meaning here? Is this a technical term exclusive to statistics?

Source: P242, America on Trial, Alan Dershowitz

Comment: Please state your question. I see a question mark but nothing near to a question. Are you asking for the definition of "statistically dispositive" or arguing its existence or validity in statistics?

Answer (score 2):

It's a relatively uncommon usage, related to *"I am **disposed** (inclined) to answer this question"*, rather than ***dis-*** being a negating prefix to ***positive***. The relevant OED definition is...

> **dispositive** Adj. Sense 3. *- having the quality or function of directing, controlling, or disposing of something; relating to direction, control, or disposal.*

That's to say when considered *statistically* (in terms of the *average net effect*) the special treatment accorded to minorities in an attempt to raise their numbers ended up being indistinguishable from the ***imposition*** of a "quota" (a target number which the system was biased to achieve regardless of the merits of individual applicants).

Comment: The “controlling” part is what matters here.  Dispositive evidence is sure proof of something.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, there is OED's definition **2**, which says *That has the quality of **disposing** or **inclining**: often opposed to **effective**, and so nearly = **preparatory, conducive, contributory**.* I wasn't exactly intimately familiar with the usage until I checked OED, and because of that definition I specifically *didn't* emphasise the word ***imposition*** in my answer (I wanted to, because it seemed etymologically pertinent). But I assume *you* know the word better than me, so I shall indulge myself with somewhat more confidence...

Comment: I don’t whether one hand knows what the other’s doing, but in this instance, check [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/dispositive) for a clearer definition.

Comment: @tchrist: Looking more closely, it seems pretty obvious you (and OxfordOnline) have the right of it. OED doesn't explicitly *say* their defn 3 (emphasis on *compelling, forcing*) is more relevant to ***legal*** contexts, but they do mention a special meaning of *dispositive clause* in Scottish law under that entry, and in fact all 6 citations seem to be "legal" contexts (which none of the citations for sense **2** are). IMHO you have been well and truly vindicated!

Comment: *Veni, vidi, vindicatus sum.*